# Visual Basic Calculator

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I need help with a calculator in visual basic.

Current code. It calculates whatever number is in the 3 different boxes and adds them up, then displays them.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    If IsNumeric(txtBoxP.Text) Then
        a = txtBoxP.Text

    End If
    If (points >= 9) Then lblPointsResult.Text = points

    If IsNumeric(txtBoxM.Text) Then
        b = txtBoxM.Text

    End If

    If points <= 0 And points > 9 Then

    End If

    If IsNumeric(txtBoxP.Text) Then
        c = txtBoxD.Text

    End If

    points = a + b + c
    lblPointsResult.Text = points
```

But I want:
I have 3 boxes to enter numbers only. But, in those 3 boxes I want the total number that can be entered to be 9. For example, if I enter in first box the number 5, second box the number 5, and third box the number 1, that is 11, so I want an error to appear.

Then, I want whatever is typed into each box to be multiplied by a certain amount after I click on Calculate button. For example, the what ever number is typed into the first box, I want it to be multiplied by 7, second box multiplied by 8, and third box multiplied by 9.

After all this, I want the answers from the three boxes to be added up and displayed

Can someone help?
Thank you.

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, and `c` declared as?  Hint: You're attempting to use `points` at the top of your code in an `If` statement, before you've even assigned it as `points = a + b + c` at the bottom of your code...